# C# Choosing class by using a Checkbox state

Tags: c#, class, checkbox, between

```
public class Europe
{
    uint Value1 = 0x12345;
}

public class UnitedStates
{
    uint Value1  = 0x54321;
}




    private uint Region(object Value)
    {
        if (EuropeCB.Checked)
        {
            return Europe.Value;    
        }
        else 
        {
            return UnitedStates.Value;
        }
    }
```

How do i go about doing this 
since it doesnt parse the value as a request for the value that was enterd in the function, you guys got any idea how i can solve this

Further explained

All i want is the uint value returned from 1 of the classes using teh same identifier withing the class

so as you can see there are 2 classes "Europe" and "UnitedStates"

and with the checkbox "EuropeCB" active  i want the function 
Region  to return from Class "Europe"instead of "UnitedStates"

So a Call will look like  Region(Value1)

With "EuropeCB"  checked it should return 0x12345  else it should return 0x54321

P.S it errors on "return Europe.Value" & "return UnitedStates.Value"  it says  "Class does not contain a definition for value"

Comment: Probably not a good idea.  Either create a `Region` base class and inherit from it, or simply make Region a property of a more general class, or even use an enum.  All of these are better options.

Comment: Talk about lack of context. What is `Region`, where does it come from, and what is `Value`, where does it come from and what is `Value`'s relationship with the returned value? What is this supposed to do and who calls it (since it's private)? And why are you trying to use a static context when the `Value1`s are instance fields?

Comment: You should really use Enums for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make them static.

```
public class Europe
{
    public static uint Value1 = 0x12345;
}

public class US
{
    public static uint Value1  = 0x54321;
}
```

Comment: Need to make them public also.

Comment: All i want is the uint value returned from 1 of the classes using teh same identifier withing the class 

so as you can see there are 2 classes "Europe" and "UnitedStates"  

and with the checkbox "EuropeCB" active  i want the function 
Region  to return from Class "Europe"instead of "UnitedStates"


So a Call will look like  Region(Value1)  

With "EuropeCB"  it should return 0x12345  else it should return 0x54321

Comment: @LaurensZalm despite your design being flawed, I suppose that if you change your code according to what it's written in this answer, you should achieve what you want.